# What is the default font used by the terminal in elementary os?

Tags: fonts

Tried font identifier online but no luck.
Is it Cousine Regular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default font for terminal is `Roboto Mono 10`.

You can find all default variables at this repository on github.com :

[elementary/default-settings](https://github.com/elementary/default-settings/blob/master/debian/elementary-default-settings.gsettings-override)